# Jasper report Error in adempiere

Tags: java, adempiere

When I am trying to run a Jasper Report,it is giving me this error.I am using this Jasper reports in adempiere technology.

**-----------> ReportStarter.ejbGetRemoteMD5: Unable to create jndi context did you deployed webApp.ear package?
Remote hashing is impossible 
12:21:15.496 ReportStarter.httpDownloadedReport: MD5 for local file is Cv0/FrUANvGZq2xkmOi1zA
-----------> ReportStarter.httpDownloadedReport: Remote hashing is not available did you deployed webApp.ear? 
-----------> ReportStarter.getRemoteFile: 404 not found: Report cannot be found on server http://[Server PC IP Address]:4911/CustomReports/barcodePrint.jasper 
12:21:15.541 ReportStarter.httpDownloadedReport:  report on server is different that local one, replacing**

Please tell me what to do,so as to solve this error.I tried to google it, but not getting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, give path to the .jrxml file not the .jasper file .

Also in order to check that the path you entered is correct you can, copy paste the path on go to URL bar in chrome and check whether is generates and XML file. If it generates an XML file on chrome the path is correct and then you can move ahead.

**P.S Check the path once the server is started.**